# approval for iOS app using Spotify API

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I have a Spotify developers key and have been preparing an iOS app for release that uses cocoalibspotify. Before I submit to Apple, I want to verify my account details and double check Spotify's approval process. But I can't find the info on developer.spotify.com for an iOS app - I just see details for a web app.

Could someone share hints or experiences of successfully publishing an iOS app that uses the Spotify API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no formal approval process other than Apple's — just submit to Apple.

However, make sure you're abiding by libspotify's Terms and Conditions, particularly the fact you can't charge money for an app that uses libspotify.

If you'd like guidance, especially with your UI components (you must make it clear that music is being played from Spotify), contact the same team you would for web apps and they can help — contact details are on the Spotify developer website.

Comment: Thanks iKenndac. I had a vague recollection of an iOS app approval form, but didn't see anything. I'm glad it was a false memory. I wish I could ^up^ your answers, but I don't yet have the points. You are my Spotify hero!

Comment: @DaveNorfleet I'd suggest accepting some more answers to get points

Comment: I see a few apps in Apple's App Store that use Spotify APIs which are free, but have in-app purchases. Is that an acceptable model for Spotify? The TOS seem to indicate otherwise.